# Choosing an element of each rows of a matrix and sum them for all possible combinations [R]

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I have a `n*n` matrix and I need to take 1 element of each row and sum them together. I need to do this for all the combinations possible and find the row and column index for the minimum one. Consider the following example:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 9
A <- matrix(round(runif(n, min = 0, max = 9)), nrow = sqrt(n), ncol = sqrt(n)) 

> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    7    4
[2,]    1    1    7
[3,]    8    4    3
```

Therefore here there are 27 possible combinations:

```
2+1+8 = 11
2+1+4 = 7
2+1+3 = 6
.
.
4+7+3 = 14
```

Therefore the expected outcome of minimum value is 6 and the index that produces minimum result is    `(1,1),(2,1),(3,3)` and `(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)`

As you can see that the solution search space is going to explode as `n` increases. Can you suggest a fast way to write this routine?

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer definitely does produce all n^n values, and so you are right does not solve the problem efficiently.

A dynamic programming approach will be more efficient:

```
smallest_sum <- function(B){
  ans = matrix(rep(NA,nrow(B)*ncol(B)), ncol=ncol(B))
  ans[1,] = B[1,]
  for (row in 2:nrow(B)){
    mn = min(ans[row-1,])
    for (col in 1:ncol(B)){
      ans[row,col] = mn + B[row,col]
    }
    print(ans)
  }
  return(ans)
}
```

The value in location (i,j) of the output from smallest_sum() contains the smallest sum that includes the value of A[i,j].

To get the index of the minimum value, just backtrack through the answer, selecting the index of the minimum value of each row:

```
backtrack <- function(ssB){
    # ssB is result from smallest_sum function
    min_ix = c()
    for (row in seq(nrow(ssB),1,-1)){
        min_ix = c(which.min(ssB[row,]), min_ix)
    }
    return(min_ix)
}
```

You can modify this to include multiple indices to get the second (and subsequent) result(s) as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a recursive solution to the problem in R:

```
perm <- function(A,level=NA){
    if (is.na(level)){
        level = nrow(A)
    }
    if (level == 1){
        return(matrix(A))
    } else{
        ans = array()
        r = perm(A[-1,], level-1)
        for (x in A[1,]){
            for (row in seq(1, nrow(r))){
                y = r[row,]
                z = array(c(x,y))
                ans = rbind(ans, array(c(x, y)))
            }
        }
    }
    return (ans[complete.cases(ans),])
}
```

Actually, this works column-wise so you'll have to use

```
perm(t(A))
```

Comment: the question doesn't have `python` tag

Comment: Yes, it should be 27. I am looking for solution in R

Comment: Sorry, I misread the tags, and have now provided an R solution

Comment: If I understand correctly it's returning all the possible combinations. Am I correct? I am skeptical that this is a fast enough solution for higher values of n.